# Configure log4j2 config file to log errors only to file

Tags: log4j2

I am trying to adapt to log4j2 and I have somewhat created a config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36}.%M() @%L - %msg%n}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green bold, DEBUG=blue bold, TRACE=blue}"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="LogToFile" fileName="src/test-output/logs/Results.log">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36}.%M() @%L - %msg%n}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green bold, DEBUG=blue bold, TRACE=blue}"/>
                <append>false</append>
        </File>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="Tests" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

What I want to achieve is that only Errors are logged to file. Please help me out how can I modify it to achieve such configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. They all involve using the Threshold Filter. The differences would be where you configure the Filter. As an alternative to the configuration below, the ThresholdFilter could also be placed on the appropriate Appender References. I should note that you asked for ONLY error events, so the configuration below filters out events at level FATAL. If you wanted those too you could simply remove the filter for FATAL. In addition, that also makes filtering on the Appender References easier as you could simply add `level="ERROR"` to the appropriate Appender References.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36}.%M() @%L - %msg%n}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green bold, DEBUG=blue bold, TRACE=blue}"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="LogToFile" fileName="src/test-output/logs/Results.log" append="false">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36}.%M() @%L - %msg%n}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green bold, DEBUG=blue bold, TRACE=blue}"/>
                <Filters>
                  <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="NEUTRAL" onMismatch="DENY"/>
                  <!-- This is only needed if ONLY error events are to be logged -->
                  <ThresholdFilter level="FATAL" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
                </Filters>
        </File>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="Tests" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>

        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```